# Where can I purchase Windows 8.1 Enterprise 64 bit online?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

I don't have local store nearby to buy a Windows copy, so I downloaded Windows 8.1, and I am looking for a trusted website to buy a Windows 8.1 Enterprise 64-bit product key online.

Comment: You can not buy Windows Enterprise version in retail (shop or online), you have to settle with Pro.

Comment: Why would you even need enterprise? (Serious q.)

Comment: Product and shopping recommendations are off-topic on Superuser. You can buy Windows license keys from microsoft.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows Enterprise can't be purchased in stores, this is a Volume licensing version for business users. Buy Pro license and reinstall Windows.